# What dimensions are possible for contours of smooth non-constant $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ functions?

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, differential-topology, morse-theory

While for $n=2$ it is pretty clear that the contours of a non-constant $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ are either extrema (and therefore points) or (the union of) 1-dimensional isolines, for $n=3$ I am already not sure whether besides points and 2-dimensional isosurfaces there is also the possibility of (1D) isolines or not.

I tried starting with a map $\gamma:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$ of a contour with $0\leqslant m\leqslant n$, and demanding

$$0 \stackrel!= df(\gamma_k(s_j)) = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m \partial_{\gamma_k} f(\vec\gamma(\vec s))\cdot \partial_{s_j}\gamma_k(\vec s)\cdot ds_j =: f_k\gamma^k_{\hphantom{k}j}ds^j.$$

For a non-vanishing gradient $f_k\neq\vec0$ (more correctly $(f_k)_k\neq\vec 0$, but I'll omit the $(\cdot)_k$ etc. for brevity) the arbitrariness of the $m$ infinitesimal elements $ds_j$ (otherwise $m$ was chosen too large) means $f_k$ must be a left-Eigenvector of $\gamma^k_{\hphantom{k}j}$, which therefore has a rank $m$ lower than $n$. But is there any further statement to make in general?

**edit** Note that with non-constant, I mean $f$ *truly* depends on $n$ variables. Of course as [Anthony Carapetis](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/523286/163) showed you can extrude the function to an arbitrary amount of additional dimensions upon which $f$ does not actually depend, e.g. $f(x,y,z) = g(x,y)$ which simply adds $z$ to the level set's variables. So the constraint I'm putting on $f$ is
$$\forall\vec x\in\mathbb R^n\forall k\in\{1,...,n\}\exists\epsilon>0\exists\vec y\in B_n(\vec x,\epsilon): \partial_k f(\vec y)\neq 0$$

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb  R$?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Oh yes of course, sorry for that typo, thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: I don't see your "pretty clear" in the first sentence. I assume that by contour you mean the level sets. What about the function $f(x) = 1$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$? The level set is all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and is not an isoline. Do you implicitly assume that $\mathrm{d}f \neq 0$?

Comment: @WillieWong I only said non-constant in the title but forgot to mention it in the body, sorry. I mean $\forall j\in\{1,...,n\}\exists \vec x\in\mathbb R^n: \partial_j f|_{\vec x}\neq 0$, i.e. no non-trivial variables **edit** I saw your tag-edit, [Morse theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory) might be what I'm looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At points $\mathrm{d}f \neq 0$, the level sets are (locally) codimension 1. In fact, for mapping $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$, if $\mathrm{d}f$ is surjective, the level sets are (locally) codimension $k$. This is the content of the [Implicit Function Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem). Part of the reason that this is true is that if $\mathrm{d}f(x): \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$ is surjective with $k$ finite, then by continuity for all $y$ where $|y-x|$ is sufficiently small, $\mathrm{d}f(y):\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$ is also surjective. That is to say, when $\mathrm{d}f$ has *maximal rank* locally the rank must be constant.

After understanding this notion we see that the implicit function theorem has the generalisation to the **Constant Rank Theorem**, a version of which reads: if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^k$ is a smooth mapping, and if $\mathrm{d}f|_U$ has constant rank $p$, where $U$ is an open subset, then locally on $U$ the level sets of $f$ are codimension $p$ submanifolds.

Now, the rank of a continuous family of matrices is semicontinuous in one direction: a small perturbation cannot decrease the rank, but can increase it (think of the family $\lambda I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix, evaluated at $\lambda = 0$). This is why that if the rank is already maximal, the hypotheses of the constant rank theorem must be satisfied automatically. But for lower ranks, this needs to be postulated.

In particular, even in the case $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, we can run into problems with saddle points. Consider the function $f(x,y) = xy$. At the origin $\mathrm{d}f = 0$, but $f^{-1}(0)$ is *not* a single point, it is in fact the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes. Therefore it is not even a topological manifold, and the usual definition of "dimension" cannot be applied to it.

Comment: Good point about your 2D-example - that level set could still be described as the union of finitely many 1D-submanifolds, which I'm tempted to also call 1D (with branches)...

Comment: @Tobias: now consider $f(x,y) = g(x)g(y)$, where $g(x) = e^{- 1/ x^2} \sin(1/x)$ when $x \neq 0$ and $g(0) = 0$. This function is smooth, and it has infinitely many zeroes, with $\{x = 0\}$ being an accumulation point of its zeroes. The point is that if $f(\vec{x}) = c$ is such that $\mathrm{d}f(\vec{x}) = 0$, then the behaviour can be quite bad.

Comment: That's indeed an example of bad behaviour... Would restricting this to _connected_ level sets improve the situation somehow? In that case your example would yield one $f(\vec x)=0$ set being the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes again which were disconnected from all the (infinitely many) other $f(\vec x)=0$ sets... Maybe [my attempted answer for $n=2,3$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/525929/163) clarifies a bit what I mean?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: the zero set $f(x,y) = 0$ is satisfied when either $g(x) = 0$ or $g(y) = 0$. The level set is, in fact, connected. It is even path connected.

Answer (score 3):

If $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ has an extremum $f(p)=C$ so that $f^{-1}(C) = \{p\}$, consider the extension $$g : \mathbb R^{n+k} \to \mathbb{R} : (x_1, \cdots, x_n, x_{n+1}, \cdots x_{n+k}) \mapsto f(x_1,\cdots,x_n).$$ The level set $g^{-1}(C)$ will simply be $\{p\}\times \mathbb R^k$, which is $k$-dimensional; so by choosing $n,k$ appropriately you can get any combination of dimensions you like.

If you want to eliminate the possibility of level sets of full dimension then "non-constant" is not enough - consider bump functions. I can't think of a simpler characterisation for this than "nowhere locally constant" which really just means that all level sets have empty interior.

Studying the differential of the function can indeed tell you about the level sets - you will probably be interested in e.g. the constant rank theorem.

Comment: Aww, that's cheating - of course I meant the _minimum_ $k$ with which $g^{-1}(C)$ can be parametrized. Ok, [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) are a real issue though - so I should ask about contours on the support only. Anyway, I just wondered [are there bump functions which have infinitely many smooth integrals?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/525572), and whether this became less cheat-able in $\mathbb C^n$...

Comment: @Tobias: I don't understand what you mean. How is this example cheating?

Comment: I mean of course you can add an arbitrary amount of coordinates to obtain the dimension you desire - but the coordinates you add convey no "meaning", they are simply dropped again. What I want to know is the smallest dimension $m$ that is sufficient to parametrize _all_ coordinates $\{\vec\gamma(\vec s)\}$ in $\mathbb R^n$ (via a parametrization $\vec s\in\mathbb R^m\subset\mathbb R^n$) that are connected to one base point $\vec x_0$ such that $f(\vec\gamma(\vec s))$ remains constant?

Comment: @Tobias: are you sure you're understanding my example correctly? I'm not parametrising the level sets at all; but it is certainly necessary to use at least $k$ dimensions to parametrise them (because they are diffeomorphic copies of $\mathbb R^k$). To be sure you're with me: when $n=2,k=1$ my example is something like $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2$, which has a 1-dimensional level set passing through the origin.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get your example, you may have to dumb it down a bit more :/ What I mean is, given e.g. $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ (so $n=2$) the contours $f(x,y)\stackrel!= r^2$ would be circles of radius $r$ and therefore be one-dimensional e.g. with a parametrisation $$\begin{pmatrix}x(s)\\y(s)\end{pmatrix} = r\begin{pmatrix}\cos(s)\\\sin(s)\end{pmatrix}$$ (while adding a second parameter $t$ could not describe additional points), but for $r=0$ the parameter $s$ would become superfluous and this would degenerate to the zero-dimensional point $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: @Tobias: right. My example is just to take quadratic functions of that form and consider them in higher-dimensional spaces, which increases the dimension of the level set. For instance for $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2$, those level sets $f(x,y,z)=r^2$ are 2-dimensional cylinders - they can be parametrised by $s$ and $z$.

Comment: Indeed, but that way you've extended $n=2$ to $n=3$, which is no longer the function one started with. I do (think I) get your point, but I am looking for the smallest $m$ such that for a _fixed_ $n$ and $\vec x_0\in\mathbb R^n$ the map $\gamma:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$ (or rather from an $m$ dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$, but let's not get too technical) parametrises the connected solutions of $f(\vec\gamma(\vec s\in\mathbb R^m)\in\mathbb R^n) \stackrel!= f(\vec x_0\in\vec\gamma(\mathbb R^m))$

Comment: @Tobias: I genuinely don't understand your qualm here. For fixed $n$, consider the functions $f_0(x_1\ldots x_n) = 0$, $f_1(x_1\ldots x_n)= x_1^2,$ $f_2(x_1\ldots x_n)= x_1^2 + x_2^2, \ldots$, $f_n(x_1\ldots x_n)= x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$. Then the level set of $f_k$ passing through 0 is a $n-k$-dimensional submanifold; thus all level set dimensions are possible. This isn't a very useful fact (Willie has some good examples of how level sets can be much more poorly behaved than this), but it answers your question as I understand it.

Comment: I get what you mean by that, but your $f_k$ is only non-constant in $k$ variables while the other ones are artificially added. I should have made my question more precise that I consider $n$ the minimum dimension in which the function can be expressed, which in your examples make $n=k$ and the level set through 0 would then always be the isolated point $\vec x=0$ and not a higher-dimensional extrusion

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that for $\vec\nabla f(\vec x_c)=0$, $\vec x_0$ is a [critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_%28mathematics%29#Several_variables) and the next order term in the Taylor series,
$$f(\vec x+d\vec x) = f(\vec x) + d\vec x^T\cdot\vec\nabla f(\vec x) + d\vec x^T\cdot H[f](\vec x)\cdot d\vec x + \mathcal O(dx^3)$$
with $H[f](\vec x)=(\partial_j\partial_k f(\vec x))_{jk}$ being the [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix), needs to be considered since the gradient term then vanishes trivially for any $d\vec x$. Since $d\vec x=(\vec\nabla\vec\gamma^T)\cdot d\vec s$, unless the Hessian also vanishes entirely the rank of $\gamma^k_{\hphantom{k}j}$ is given by the amount of zero-Eigenvalues of the Hessian, i.e. $$\vec\nabla f = \vec 0 \Rightarrow \operatorname{rk}\gamma^k_{\hphantom{k}j} = n - \operatorname{rk} H[f]$$
Note how a full rank of the Hessian, even if its Eigenvalues are of mixed sign, still implies an isolated level point. If the Hessian also vanishes, even higher order derivative tensors need to be considered, though at that point it might by easier to check $\vec x_c$'s environment instead.

If $\vec f\neq0$, for $n=2$ note that $\gamma^k_{\hphantom{k}j}(x,y)\propto\begin{pmatrix}\partial_y f\\-\partial_x f\end{pmatrix}$, so $m_\text{1D}=1$.

For $n=3$ and $m=3$, $\gamma^k_{\hphantom{k}j}(x,y,z)$ must be similar to
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -\partial_z f & \partial_y f
\\ \partial_z f & 0 & -\partial_x f
\\ -\partial_y f & \partial_x f & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
Since the rank of a skew-symmetric matrix is even, the only possible ranks are 0 and 2, the former of which does however require $\vec\nabla f=0$ and therefore requires observing the Hessian instead. Rank two describes isosurfaces and in order to reduce the parametrization for the rank 2 case, simply split this matrix into the product of a $3\times 2$ matrix and a $2\times 3$ matrix and multiply the latter by $d(s_1,s_2,s_3)^T$ to obtain two independent parameters. So, for $\vec\nabla f\neq0$, $m_{\text{3D}}=2$. <del>Especially, **the level sets of $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ functions are never 1D.**</del> However, for $\vec\nabla f=0$, the Hessian can have a rank of 2, which would give $\gamma^k_{\hphantom{k}j}$ a rank of 1.

For a general $n\geqslant2$ note that any vector obtained by multiplying $\vec\nabla f$ by a skew-symmetric matrix is orthogonal to $\vec\nabla f$. Now for $n(n-1)/2$ linearly independent parameters construct such a skew symmetric matrix $A_j$ to obtain $\gamma^k_{\hphantom{k}j} = (A_1\vec\nabla f, ..., A_{n(n-1)/2}\vec\nabla f)$ - with way too many degrees of freedom for $n\geqslant 4$ of course. But the rank of this $n\times n(n-1)/2$ matrix is the minimal $m$ sought for. I'm not yet sure what $m(n)$ are possible for $n\geqslant 4$ though...

Comment: Hm, $f(x,y,z)=xyz$ has rank zero along each axis, despite $f(x,y,z)\equiv 0$ being the intersection of the $x=0, y=0$ and $z=0$ planes... So probably either an open subset or the local Hessian matrix have to be considered as well