# Are there bump functions which have infinitely many smooth integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

While it is well-known that [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) are smooth yet non-analytic $C^\infty$ functions, I was wondering if like the latter bump functions do also possess infinitely many smooth integrals, i.e.

> Given a bump function $f(x)=:f_0(x)$, let $f_{n+1}(x):=\int_{a_n}^x f_n(y)\,dy$. Is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ smooth?

---

As [John pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525572/are-there-bump-functions-which-have-infinitely-many-smooth-integrals#comment1124430_525572) unless the integration boundary $a_n$ can be chosen such that $f_n$ is also a bump function, the answer might be no. Then the question would boil down to whether there exists a series of *infinitely many* non-trivial bump functions which are the integral of one another.

Comment: If $f$ is a bump function, then $f_1 = C$ for all $x$ large, and thus $f_2$ is like a linear function, and so on so forth. Limit does not exist.

Comment: @John Good point, so the integration boundaries should be chosen such that the constant is zero **edit** oh wait, that may not be possible. Actually you basically answered the question: Unless the integral boundaries can be chosen such that $f_n$ outside the support is zero on _both_ sides for all $n$, the limit does not exist and therefore most (all?) bump functions cannot be smoothly integrated infinitely many times

Comment: Your definition of $f_{n+1}$ is wrong, it should read (for instance) $f_{n+1}(a)=\int_0^a f(x)\mathrm dx$. Note that one chooses only _one_ integral boundary, the other is the function argument. And the argument by @John does not seem to show that the pointwise limit of $f_n(x)$ could not exist. I do think there is an interesting question hidden here!

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Ok, I fixed to an arbitrary lower boundary (I was assuming an indefinite integral would imply an integration constant the choice of which were just as arbitrary). Please let me know if there is anything else one could add to reveal the interesting part of my question a bit more :7

Comment: Consider for instance $f_0$ to be a Dirac function at $0$ (not really a bump function, but easier to compute with). Taking integrals with lower bound $<0$, the functions $f_n$ will be identically $0$ for $x<0$, while for $x>0$ one gets $f_n(x)=\frac1{(n-1)!}x^{n-1}$, which converges to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ for any $x$. Not a very exciting limit, but certainly a smoooth one.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Good example! I wonder if that still works when taking one of the limit-representations of the Dirac distribution and swapping the limits...