# Given a vector $\vec x$, are all vectors perpendicular to it constructible from skew-symmetrix matrices multiplied by $\vec x$?

Tags: linear-algebra

As noted [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/525929/163), given a skew-symmetric matrix $S$ the vector $\vec x^T S$ is orthogonal to $\vec x$ since
$$\vec x^T S\vec x = -\vec x^T S^T\vec x = -(\vec x^T S\vec x)^T = -\vec x^T S\vec x = 0.$$

But is the converse also true, i.e. $\forall\vec y\perp\vec x\exists S=-S^T: \vec y = S\vec x$?

Comment: Mayve you could compute the dimension of the vector space of all vectors perpendicular to $x$, and compute the dimension of the vector space of all vectors $Sx$ with $S$ skew-symmetric.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Funny you mention that, because originally I was looking for precisely that dimension and one Ansatz required this conjecture being true...

Comment: ...[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534389/given-a-vector-vec-x-what-is-the-maximum-possible-rank-for-a-matrix-a-such)'s the question about the orthogonal space's dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dimension of vector space is no less than 3, then for any $y\in\mathbb R^n (n\geq3)$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle=0$ there's always a skew-symmetric matrix $A$ such that $y=Ax$.

Consider linear equations $y=Ax$, since $A$ is skew-symmetric, it has $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ unknowns to determine. On the other hand, we have $n$ equations. So the solution exists if and only if
$$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-n=\frac{n(n-3)}{2}\geq0$$
which implies $n\geq3$

Comment: Something peculiar here, as it works for $n=2$, when this argument says it shouldn't. If $x=(a,b)$ and $x\cdot y=0$ then $y=(bc,-ac)$ for some $c$ so $y=Ax$ where $$A=\pmatrix{0&c\cr-c&0\cr}$$ is skew-symmetric.